# Python logging sys.exit('message')

Tags: python, logging, exit

I followed [this guide](http://victorlin.me/posts/2012/08/26/good-logging-practice-in-python) on how to take advantage of Python's `logging` module.

Now I each of my .py files get its logger by calling

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

The main .py file sets up logging reading a json configuration file.

```
import os
import json
import logging.config


def setup_logging(
    default_path='logging.json',
    default_level=logging.INFO,
    env_key='LOG_CFG'
):
    path = default_path
    value = os.getenv(env_key, None)
    if value:
        path = value
    if os.path.exists(path):
        with open(path, 'rt') as f:
            config = json.load(f)
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=default_level)


setup_logging()
```

However, I have a lot of code that was written without proper logging that simply prints an error message before exiting.

```
# when error occurs
sys.exit('error message')
```

I'd like to know if there's a way to capture those errors, format them in the same way as other errors (with timestamp) and save them in the same a `error.log` file used by the logger.

This is my configuration file, logging.json

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": false,
    "formatters": {
        "simple": {
            "format": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
        }
    },

    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout"
        },

        "info_file_handler": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "filename": "info.log",
            "maxBytes": 10485760,
            "backupCount": 20,
            "encoding": "utf8"
        },

        "error_file_handler": {
            "class": "logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler",
            "level": "ERROR",
            "formatter": "simple",
            "filename": "errors.log",
            "maxBytes": 10485760,
            "backupCount": 20,
            "encoding": "utf8"
        }
    },

    "loggers": {
        "my_module": {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "handlers": ["console"],
            "propagate": false
        }
    },

    "root": {
        "level": "DEBUG",
        "handlers": ["console", "info_file_handler", "error_file_handler"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since [sys.exit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) is implemented by raising the SystemExit exception, you can catch the exception and log it:

```
import logging
import sys
import os

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger('example')

def function_will_exit():
    sys.exit('some error log')

try:
    function_will_exit()
except SystemExit as e:
    # this log will include traceback
    logger.exception('function_will_exit failed with exception')
    # this log will just include content in sys.exit
    logger.error(str(e))

    # if you don't need exception traceback from Python
    # os._exit(1)
    raise
```

Comment: Nice. This won't require many changes and has the added benefit of being able to log a full exception trace. However, I get a double log in the console, one in standard error (red, unformatted) and the other in standard output (black, with timestamp). Any way to only keep the logger print without completely silencing standard error in console?

Comment: @Agostino the stderr output is caused by raised exception. It's not written by logging. when error log is configured to a file, you will not get double log in the file.

Comment: The error log is fine. I get the double log in console. I was hoping for a way to "capture" the error message so it's written only if it's not logged. Perhaps logging errors are something more than just things commonly written to standard error. Maybe I'm confused.

Comment: @Agostino There's way to silently exit python program without exception, I've updated my answer, you can try it. However it's not recommended, you have been warned :-)